# Recording Audio in MVC3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, audio-recording

I am currently searching for a tool that will allow a user to make and save recordings in an MVC3 Application.

I know this can be accomplished by using Silverlight, Flash, or ActiveX methods, however I was interested if it could be done in an easy/elegant method.

Ideally the workflow would function as follows:

- User clicks the Record button.
- If user has a microphone, recording begins, otherwise user is notified that recording is not possible
- User clicks the Record button to stop recording
- User is prompted to save the recording

If anyone knows of any tools to easily integrate into an MVC application, or perhaps something that will point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks to HTML5, there is a elegant solution at http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by *elegant* you mean pure javascript I am afraid that this is not possible. You will need to use a client side plugin. Here's an example of [audio recorder with Silverlight](http://blog.ondrejsv.com/post/Audio-recorder-Silverlight-4-sample.aspx).

Comment: This is the exact Silverlight method that I was referring to in the question. I suppose that what I was looking for was a simpler interface, perhaps just a Record button. (As far as what is seen in the application)

Comment: @Rionmonster, you could tweak the Silverlight application GUI and fit it to your needs including only the buttons you need.

Answer (score 2):

If your not using Flash, Silverlight, ActiveX, Java or any other plugin you are not going to be able to access low level audio on the client. This of course is for security reasons, either way each plugin has its own security policies within the system.

My suggestion is look into any of these an select the best one, that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Clearest way is to allow user to upload audio files.

If this is not suitable use client side programming.